# putting specifc number of element in a row in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have one application. `form data` is coming from `backend`. sometimes element can be `10` sometimes `3` sometimes `5`. I need to put exactly `3 element in a row`. if there are more than `3` they should be in next `row`.
How can I achieve this using `html/css` or `bootstrap`.

In below example there are 7 elements. so there should be 3 row. in first 2 row there should be 3 element and in last row exactly 1. how can achieve this?

Below is the code. how can I inject the css on same.

```
 return (
      <div>
        <FormValidator emitter={this.emitter} />
        <div className='react-form-builder-form'>
          <form encType='multipart/form-data' action={this.props.form_action} method={this.props.form_method}>
            { this.props.authenticity_token &&
              <div style={formTokenStyle}>
                <input name='utf8' type='hidden' value='&#x2713;' />
                <input name='authenticity_token' type='hidden' value={this.props.authenticity_token} />
                <input name='task_id' type='hidden' value={this.props.task_id} />
              </div>
            }
            {items}
          </form>
          <div>
            {validationList}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

[image]

when I applied

```
   .form__container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .form__container input {
      width: 33.33%;
    }



<div className='form__container'>
          <form encType='multipart/form-data' action={this.props.form_action} method={this.props.form_method}>
            { this.props.authenticity_token &&
              <div style={formTokenStyle}>
                <input name='utf8' type='hidden' value='&#x2713;' />
                <input name='authenticity_token' type='hidden' value={this.props.authenticity_token} />
                <input name='task_id' type='hidden' value={this.props.task_id} />
              </div>
            }
            {items}
          </form>
          <div>
```

it is coming like below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to add these styles to the parent of form inputs.

```
.form__container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and assign a width to your input field.

```
.form__container input {
   width: 33.33%;
}
```

Comment: Its not working, I have edited the question. I mean partially working

Comment: I think you have some label or parent class on input.
can you share a screenshot of your form source code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex box to achieve this.

you can apply css in this manner to Outer and Inner elements:

```
.outer-container { display: flex; }
.inner-element { width: 33.33% }
```

In your case outer element will be the form container and inner element will be the input elements.

Comment: I applied the same it is not working Deove

Comment: Could you please share your code in stackblitz react?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using bootstrap with the grid system, using a container div with a row class, with several elements justify alignment and have divs with the col-4 class each, by mapping your array, in this case items, and returning this jsx  to populate your data in rows of 3 elements that will be fairly distributed in the existing area of your items rendering section. Let me provide with a quick example of the mapping of this **[bootStrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)** approach. Hope this helps!

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">      
<div>
   <FormValidator emitter={this.emitter} />
   <div className='react-form-builder-form'>
      <form encType='multipart/form-data' action={this.props.form_action} method={this.props.form_method}>
         { this.props.authenticity_token &&
         <div style={formTokenStyle}>
            <input name='utf8' type='hidden' value='&#x2713;' />
            <input name='authenticity_token' type='hidden' value={this.props.authenticity_token} />
            <input name='task_id' type='hidden' value={this.props.task_id} />
         </div>}
         <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
            {items.map((item, ind) =>(  
            <div key={ind} className="col-4">
               <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1" className="form-label">items.label</label>
               <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Lorem" />
            </div>
            ));}
         </div>
   </div>
   </>
   </form>
   <div>
      {validationList}
   </div>
</div>
</div> 
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: its not working Alvison

Comment: in this case, you should use your own array and map-loop it with the example I gave you as a base. Your shared code didn't have specific arrays to run this with, hence I only gave you the approach you might take, however, you still need to customize to your own.